# JavaScript how to mock confirm method

Tags: javascript

I have following code in my JavaScript code.

```
if (window.confirm('Are you sure?')) {
    AdminData.actOnResult('delete');
}
```

I am writing test for this piece of code. How do I mock window.confirm method? I tried following code but it did not work.

```
window.confirm = function(arg) {
    return true;
};
```

I can move the window.confirm method to another function and then I can mock that method. However I was wondering if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

Your own code works fine for me in IE.  Just the following *in the global scope* should override it:

```
var confirm = function () { return true; }
```

**EDIT**
I've seen a few questions on SO in the past about trying to override `confirm`, mostly because they don't like it (and who would?).  If you're trying to bypass it for this sort of reason, I suggest you look at changing your code to implement a callback-based replacement for confirm.  Take a look at [jQuery UI's modal confirm](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation) for a good example of this.

Answer (score 2):

I am using Jasmine for unit testing and have mocked alert and confirm with the following

```
alert = function (alertString) {debug.log('ALERT:', alertString);};

var confirmValue = true; //set this before you expect the confirm statement to be shown
confirm = function (confirmString) {
    debug.log('CONFIRM:', confirmString, confirmValue);
    return confirmValue;
};
```

Then I can say:

```
describe("test", function () {
    it('should test true confirm workflow', function () {
        confirmValue = true; // or false if you like
        //expect outcomes that would come from any confirms being called with true
    });
});
```

It's not perfect, and if you have multiple confirms that could pop between setting that confirmValue, you could be in trouble. Perhaps then it would be good to setup a cue of expected confirm return values... tricky...

Comment: IMO of the 3 answers so far, this one addresses what Nick is asking. There's very little on Stackoverflow today about static mocking in Javascript besides your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd think about implementing a wrapper around static methods on the window (or other) object.  Then provide your wrapper to whatever uses the static method.  Obviously this is easier if you are using a "class"-based implementation.  Then, in order to mock the method, simply provide a different wrapper that returns the value that you want.

```
var windowWrapper = {
    confirm: function(msg) { return confirm(msg); },
    ...
};

var mockWrapper = {
    confirm: function(msg) { return true; },
    ...
}

var wrapper = windowWrapper;
if (test) {
    wrapper = mockWrapper;
}
```

...

```
if (wrapper.confirm('Are you sure?')) {   
    AdminData.actOnResult('delete');   
}
```